# Tensorflow inference with single image with CIFAR-10 example

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to inference single image using tensorflow cifar10 example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#convolutional-neural-networks

> ```
> def restore_vars(saver, sess):
>         """ Restore saved net, global score and step, and epsilons OR
>         create checkpoint directory for later storage. """
>         #sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
>
>         ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
>         if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
>           # Restores from checkpoint
>           saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
>           return True
>         else:
>           print('No checkpoint file found')
>           return False
>
>
>     def eval_single_img():
>         input_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file("test.jpg"), channels=3)
>         input_img = 
>         input_img = tf.reshape(input_img, [3, 32, 32])
>         input_img = tf.transpose(input_img, [1, 2, 0])
>         reshaped_image = tf.cast(input_img, tf.float32)
>
>         resized_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(reshaped_image, 24, 24)
>
>         float_image = tf.image.per_image_whitening(resized_image)
>
>         image = tf.expand_dims(float_image, 0)  # create a fake batch of images (batch_size = 1)
>
>
>         logits = cifar10.inference(image)
>
>         _, top_k_pred = tf.nn.top_k(logits, k=5)
>
>         # Restore the moving average version of the learned variables for eval.
>         variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(
>              cifar10.MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY)
>         variables_to_restore = variable_averages.variables_to_restore()
>         saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
>
>         with tf.Session() as sess:
>             restored = restore_vars(saver, sess)
>
>             top_indices = sess.run([top_k_pred])
>             print ("Predicted ", top_indices[0], " for your input image.")
> ```

**ERROR MESSAGE:
        tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [18,384] rhs shape= [2304,384]
                 [[Node: save/Assign_5 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@local3/weights"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](local3/weights, save/restore_slice_5)]]
        Caused by op u'save/Assign_5', defined at:

```
    What might be causing this?**
```

Comment: I'm assuming you trained with a batch size of 128 but now are only passing in a single image? That is where the  18 vs 2304 is coming from in the tensor shapes. This is because the cifar10 example does not use placeholders with a None dimension for input and are therefore not flexible later on when restoring a graph with different input shapes(I think). Other answers have said to add such placeholders like the minst tutorial but I am unsure how to combine that with the cifar 10 input queue.